# Data Grid View...programmatically setting the select row index doesn't set the CurrentRow.Index to the same?

Tags: vb.net, user-interface, datagridview, indexing, rows

This code

```
CurrentSelectedRow = Me.dgvPreviouslyCut.CurrentRow.Index
```

stores the current selected row that has been clicked by the user in a data grid view control .
After refreshing the datasource for the data grid view, this code

```
Me.dgvPreviouslyCut.Rows(CurrentSelectedRow).Selected = True
```

programmatically re-selects the same row.

Immediately afterwards though

```
 Me.dgvPreviouslyCut.CurrentRow.Index
```

is always set to zero, NOT the variable CurrentSelectedRow as you would expect.

Why does programmatically setting the select row index not cause the property CurrentRow.Index to be set to the same?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`CurrentRow` is the row containing the currently active cell. When you bind the DataGridView to an external data source, this property is reset to its default value which is the first cell in the first column.

`SelectedRow` is the row which is currently selected/highlighted. It may be one or more rows depending on `MultiSelect` property. To select a row you have to set its `Selected` property to true.

By setting the row as selected you merely keeping it highlighted not making it active.

To retain the current cell you have to store the Current cell's row and column index. To get them use the `CurrentCellAddress` property. Once your refresh the `DataSource` set the CurrentCell property using these indexes.

```
dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1.Rows(rowindex).Cells(columnindex);
```

Comment: I've tried setting the current cell, but it seems to only accept a cell object from the current version of the datagridview.  And I haven't found a way to specify the currrent cell programatically. There's no row property in a datagridview. Are you sure your code is correct?

Comment: @Killakeys Sorry for the typo in code. I have modified my code. Yes, you have to set the `currentcell` from the current version of the datagridview. Thats why I am getting the cell using the indexes from the datagridview.

Comment: just for completion of you right and useful answer. ColumnIndex must be an index of a visible column, or it will trow an exception

Answer (score 1):

The `DataGridView` creates a new [CurrencyManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.currencymanager%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) when the data source is changed. If this CM contains items, the default position is `0`, thus pushing this to the DGV and selects the first row.

To fix this, just set the position of the CM instead:

```
Me.dgvPreviouslyCut.DataSource = my_new_datasource

Dim cm As CurrencyManager = CType(Me.BindingContext(my_new_datasource), CurrencyManager)

If ((Me.CurrentSelectedRow > -1) AndAlso (Me.CurrentSelectedRow < cm.Count)) Then
    cm.Position = Me.CurrentSelectedRow
End If
```

Comment: My data source is a recordset from SQL Server 2008 database. It's Count property is 1. I'm thinking that's because it has one datamember, which is called 'CurData'.  How would I change the position inside of that datamember?

Comment: @Killakeys A `recordset` is pretty vague, what is the object type?

Comment: It's actually a dataset. I used the other suggestion as it was a little more straightforward. Thanks for the help though, I know a little more about bindings now!

Answer (score 0):

A simple trick is to get the current row index:

```
int RowNumber = YourDataGridView.CurrentRow.Index;
```

After refreshing the datasource/datagridview, you can re-select the previous row index using:

```
YourDataGridView.ClearSelection();
YourDataGridView.CurrentCell = YourDataGridView.Rows[RowNumber].Cells[0];
```

That should re-select the previowsly selected row with the correct index.