# how to change the selected row in datagridview from code behind

Tags: c#, datagridview

Actually im not sure if its called selected index, selected row or not. if not, can someone tell me whats the name of this pointer and how am i able to change it in datagridview?

[image]

Comment: Check this Post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22304743/data-grid-view-programmatically-setting-the-select-row-index-doesnt-set-the-c

Comment: To spell it out: You need to set some cell in the target row as `CurrentCell = yourDGV[somecolumn,yourRow]` -  And if you want to can then in addition select that row , by setting `Currentrow.Selected = true`

Comment: i dont know how to thank you guys!

Answer (score 1):

It's `SelectedRows`. [Link to MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectedrows%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

To change it in the code behind, you'd need to retrieve the index of the row you want to select and change its `Selected` property to `true`

So as an example, if your DataGridView is called `myDataGridView` has 25 rows, you wanted to select the 15th row programatically. You'd do:

```
myDataGridView.Rows[14].Selected = true;
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Not quite. This, for example, doesn't take mulitselect into account. See the above comments for the correct answer!

Comment: Surely with MultiSelect though you can just make additional calls to the rows you want to select if the DataGridView control has MultiSelect enabled. It's been a while since I've used multiselect on a DataGridView so I've probably missed a detail somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

To change the selected row index you should use the CurrentCell method, then give the row number you're trying to set the focus on:

```
YourDataGridView.CurrentCell = YourDataGridView.Rows[RowNumber].Cells[0];
```